# Problem accessing events in Google Resource Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use Google Apps Script to interrogate a resource calendar. I am using the `getEvents(start,end)` method to try to get an array of events in the calendar. This works fine if I use my default personal calendar, but when I use a resource calendar, even though it is recognised as a calendar object I get the error

> xxxx.getEvents is not a function.

It suggests to me that the `getEvents()` method doesn't work for resource calendars for some reason?

```
Logger.log(calendarName);
// load calendar for faulty kit
var kitCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName);

// set start date today and end date one year from now
var startDate = new Date();
var endDate = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1));

Logger.log(startDate);
Logger.log(endDate);
Logger.log(kitCalendar);

events = kitCalendar.getEvents(startDate,endDate);
```

```
Execution log
9:07:21 PM  Notice  Execution started
9:07:22 PM  Info    (Test kit item)-Dummy resource calendar 1 for testing
9:07:23 PM  Info    Tue Nov 08 21:07:23 GMT+00:00 2022
9:07:23 PM  Info    Wed Nov 08 21:07:23 GMT+00:00 2023
9:07:23 PM  Info    [Calendar]
9:07:23 PM  Error   
TypeError: kitCalendar.getEvents is not a function
addFault    @ Code.gs:28
```

Comment: This `CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)` returns an array not a calendar.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks, apologies for the trivial mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var kitCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
```

[getCalendarsByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarsByName(String))